# I am developing my own python package, but Omnicomplete won't recognize it

Tags: gvim, vimscript-python, python

I have my package in a local folder (say `C:/Users/Myself/PythonStuff/MyPackage`).
Next, I created a new file in `C:/Users/Myself/PythonStuff` where I import my package, i.e. on top of my new file I have

```
import MyPackage as mp
```

and on `Vim` I type `:cd C:/Users/Myself/PythonStuff`.

Now, if in my newly created file I type `mp.` followed by `<c-x><c-o>` I get a `PatterNotFound` error.
I am suspicious that I should tell Vim to look also into `C:/Users/Myself/PythonStuff` but I have no idea how to do that.